Highlight text containing commands - cite, footnote, ref, etc
This seems quite important omission but latex obviously doesn't handle it well, from my looking for solutions to this.
I want to find a way to easily highlight text (as you would do using textbf or color commands) which contains commands like cite, footnote, etc. Basically as you would in a regular word processor.
I can't find any solution to this. Either they don't work with citations, or they use boxes where the footnotes are generated at the end of the box rather than the page, or they require you to change the footnotes, wrap commands etc, which isn't really practical.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\refs.bib}
@article{smith,
    author = {Smith, J.},
    title = {{Name}},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--10},
    year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

So this text should be highlighted properly {\cite{smith}} and it shouldn't run off the page when highlighted, \ref{fig}.

\end{document}

I'm using pdfLaTeX
Would appreciate if anyone knows a solution to this. Thanks!
Edit: I know you can do this using lualatex, but I'd rather find a solution without this

You should perhaps explain what exactly you mean by highlight, which tools did you try and what did not work. Concrete examples are always appeciated.

Highlight as you would in regular word process - I.e. background color - and I've have pretty much tried everything I can find, so would take a long time to list! Nothing worked - using soul, and variously defining this; xcolor; tcolorbox; mdframed; etc

I suggest to include at least one way of highlighting to demonstrate the problem.

Use lualatex and the lua-ul package with pdflatex it doesn't work.
